# Why is ruby gem method returning variable of the wrong class

Tags: ruby, x12

I'm using the hippo gem to parse X12 files into their segments and values. I am using the parser method and I expected it to return variables of the class: Hippo::TransactionSets::Hippa_837::Base but the value returned is of class Array. Within the library I can put the quantity I need into a global variable and access it that way but I don't think I should have to do that. I tried to create a variable of the class and set its value with the parser method return, so far no luck with that.

```
begin  
require 'rubygems'
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'pp'
require 'pry'
require 'hippo'

t = Hippo::Parser.parse_string(File.read('c:/test.edi'))
puts "DONE: "
puts t.class
puts $t.class
gets
puts $t.ST
end
```

The output:

```
DONE: 
Hippo::TransactionSets::HIPAA_837::Base
Array
ST*837*0021*005010X222A1~
```

$t is the global variable I set in the parser.rb lib file. t turns out to be an array class without the methods to access segments.

Comment: Could you post a code example illustrating this?

Comment: Ruby:begin  
 require 'rubygems'
 gem 'minitest'
 require 'minitest/autorun'
 require 'pp'
 require 'pry'
    require 'hippo'

 t = Hippo::Parser.parse_string(File.read('c:/test.edi'))
 puts "DONE: "
 puts t.class
 puts $t.class
 gets
    puts $t.ST

end

Comment: That did not work, I will try to edit the post with the source and output. Thanks

Comment: That's better, it seem to me that the variable t should be the hippo class so that one can access segments via its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the array, or fetch individual elements, and then you will find the objects you expect, with all the methods associated to segments.